# How to find elements with not enough observations in a list

Tags: r, list

Say I have the following list where each element is a data.frame of different sizes

```
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(12346), ncol = 2))
df2 <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(14330), ncol = 2))
df3 <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(2422), ncol = 2))

l <- list(df1, df2, df3)
```

In my example each data.frame represents a year of observations, and clearly `df3` contains a lot fewer observations compared to the other two.

My question is then:
What is the best approach to detect those elements of the list `l` that does not compare in the number of rows and then remove them from the list?

I've so far tried using the median but as this should always remove half of the elements in `l` I'm not sure this is the best solution for future use

```
library(collapse)
cutoff <- input %>%
      vapply(nrow, FUN.VALUE = length(.) %>%
      median()
  
idx <- dapply(X = input, FUN = function(x) nrow(x) >= cutoff)
    
input[idx]
```

where `input` is a list as the above `l`

NOTE: As this is my first question on SO, please feel free to edit the question if it does not live up the standards of this community or give feedback on asking better questions. Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**
The question is not so much on how to use median to remove elements of the list, but rather IF median is the right method to remove those `data.frames` which have a lot less observations than the others

Comment: I think you’re asking how to identify outliers (dfs in your list that have *uncharacteristically* low numbers of rows), and that’s hard to answer without knowing how reliable your df row number is and how it’s distributed. This is a stats question, not a programming one, and there’s no univocal answer, but a common start is IQR * 1.5, or read up here: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2016/12/outlier-detection-and-treatment-with-r/

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is missing a clear question that can be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a variable number of rows in your data frames, and you want to identify those that are *unusually* low. This is a statistical problem called **outlier detection**.

Programmatically, you want to extract the number of rows from your list of data frames, which is easily done with

```
rows <- sapply(l, nrow)
```

Statistically, you now want to take a look at your data and its distribution. Good, simple visualisations in R can be

```
hist(rows)
boxplot(rows)
```

Note that these will work better if you have many dfs, and are pretty useless with 3.

How to now determine which values are outside an "expected" distribution is not always trivial. Some resources:

- `outliers` tag on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outliers)
- a nice [RBloggers post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2016/12/outlier-detection-and-treatment-with-r/)

Note that it's also acceptable for you to *choose* a cutoff manually if you can reasonably justify it.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
l[sapply(l, function(x) nrow(x) >= median(unlist(lapply(l, nrow))))]
```

Answer (score 1):

`purrr::keep` is the way to go when filtering lists with conditions.

```
library(purrr)

keep(l, ~ nrow(.x) > median(map_dbl(l, nrow)))
```